# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.firefox' has no attribute 'find_element_by_name' using Selenium through Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, module, findelement

```
from selenium import webdriver
drivers = webdriver.firefox
elem = drivers.find_element_by_name("username")
```

So above is the script I wrote but every time I run it returns this error message:

> AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.firefox' has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'

Comment: `webdriver.Firefox()`

Comment: Thank you it work, i was calling the module the way it was written in the folder. I didn't know I had to capitalize it.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.firefox' has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'
```

...implies that the **selenium.webdriver.firefox** has no attribute as `find_element_by_name`.

---

You need to consider a couple of things as follows:

- To initialize a *Firefox* session you need to change the line of code `drivers = webdriver.firefox` into proper format as:

  ```
  drivers = webdriver.Firefox()
  ```
- `find_element_by_name()` method can locate the element only when the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) is loaded. So, you need to invoke `get(url)` and load the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) before invoking `find_element_by_name()` as follows:

  ```
  drivers.get("http://digitalsaf.com/")
  ```
- Your effective code block will be:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  driver.get("http://digitalsaf.com/")
  elem = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
  ```